# Navigation transition, overriding negations

Tags: css, navigation, fade, transition

I am trying to apply an ease in ease out (with a fade) in the navigation as it scrolls between each section of my one page scrolling site. It is currently working on the transition from the first section (welcome) to the second section (mission).

I am using `squarespace` and am doing `custom CSS` overrides to the elements I want to change. I can see that there are some negations in `squarespace's` CSS for the transitions, is there a way for me to override this?

[**Demo Site**](http://www.the-caterers.com/)

The code is as follows:

```
body:not(.always-use-overlay-nav) .nav-wrapper nav>div a, 
body:not(.always-use-overlay-nav) .nav-wrapper nav span>div a,
body:not(.always-use-overlay-nav) .nav-wrapper nav>div label,
body:not(.always-use-overlay-nav) .nav-wrapper nav span>div label {
  -webkit-transition: color .1s 0s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: color .1s 0s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: color .1s 0s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: color .1s 0s ease-in-out;
  transition: color .1s 0s ease-in-out;}
```

For some reason all of the transitions are being "crossed-out" when I inspect the element on my site.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: @NathanTuggy Is this what you meant?

Comment: That's closer, but the relevant HTML is probably useful too, and I strongly suspect there's other CSS that's crucial to the problem. Try to make sure this post has enough on its own to reconstruct the basic problem.